# Pointer or address?

Tags: c, pointers, cs50

```
// Capitalizes a copy of a string while checking for errors

#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Get a string
    char *s = get_string("s: "); //this is in the cs50.h
    char *t = malloc((strlen(s) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    // Copy string into memory
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i <= n; i++)
        t[i] = s[i];

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is from cs50 2018 lecture #3 . `t[i] = s[i]` part confused me. As I know, when we say `char *t` , `t` will store the address of the first part of the memory that was allocated. So doesn't `t[i]` give us the address of the memory at `t[i]` location ? If it is like so, shouldn't we write
`*t[i] = s[i]` to change the value of `t[i]` ?

Comment: the brackets `[ ]` automatically dereference. `t[i]` is equivalent to `*(t+i)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `[]` array index operator *dereferences* the pointer and evaluates to the value itself, not its address. The expression `s[i]` is equivalent to the expression `*(s + i)`. If you wanted the address of the element at index `i`, you would need to use the `&` operator, as in `&s[i]` (which is equivalent to `s + i`).

```
int array[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };  // create an array for illustration
int *ptr = array;                  // array type decays to a pointer

// these print the same thing: the address of the array element at index 2
printf("%p\n", ptr + 2);      // pointer arithmetic
printf("%p\n", &ptr[2]);      // array index operator followed by address-of operator

// these print the same thing: the element at index 2 (= 30)
printf("%d\n", *(ptr + 2));   // pointer arithmetic followed by dereference operator
printf("%d\n", ptr[2]);       // array index operator
```

Answer (score 2):

`t[i]` actually gives you the `i`th element of the array.  It works the same as `s[i]`, which has the same type.

The syntax `t[i]` is exactly the same as `*(t + i)`.  In other words, pointer arithmetic is performed to get a pointer to the desired element, then the result is dereferenced to get the actual element.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *s = ...;
char *t = ...;
...
t[i] = s[i];
```

`t[i]` is an *lvalue*, an expression that refers to an object.  Oversimplifying a bit [*], if it appears on the left side of an assignment (as it does here), it refers to a particular `char` object, and the assignment updates the value of that object. `s[i]` is similar, but it appears on the right side of the assignment, so it yields the *value* of the object.

It's essentially the same thing as:

```
int x;
int y;
y = x;
```

`x` and `y` are both names of objects, and they're both lvalues.  The `y` on the left hand side refers to the object. The `x` on the right hand side yields the value stored in the object.

[*] The oversimplification is that there are contexts other than the left hand side of an assignment in which an lvalue refers to an object rather than yielding its value.

There's a bit more going on here in the way the `[]` operator is defined (see the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/)) section 6 for the relationship between arrays and pointers), but in this case all you really need to know is that `s[i]` and `t[i]` are the names of objects.

The gory details are in the C standard, [N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.3.2.1.